# LED Banner in Swift using views

Tags: swift, performance, animation, view, led

I try to create an animated LED Banner. I can create letter views using a 5x8 digit display and make the the text move (https://github.com/drollig8/LEDBanner.git): The problem: with only a 10 letter text iOS will have to refresh 400 views 25 times per second. This kind of kills the CPU.

What can I do to make this endeavour more energy-saving?

Comment: What about using a font instead of LEDs. Is it an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach for a right-to-left scrolling display.

1. Create a custom view that can draw a 5x8 cell with its drawRect function.
2. Use 11 of these views to represent your display. Add them as subviews to an appropriately size view.
3. Every 1/25 of a second, move the 11 views and if the leftmost one has scrolled off the end, move it to the right side and update it with new letter data.

Comment: Well that sounds like the content of the cell stays fix. But with a smooth scrolling the letters have to "slide through" the cell which means I have to create a new cell 25 times per second. And each cell must contain 40 subviews to display the "bits" or "digits".

Comment: You move the cells 1/5 of a cell left each 1/25 of a second.  The bits are rectangle fills. Look at how to draw filled rectangles in a drawRect routine. This method would use 12 views total, and a new letter would only be drawn as it first entered the screen.

Comment: You could do it this way using subviews to represent the bits. You'd only create as many subviews of the cell as there are "on" bits. Scrolling a letter would still be as simple as moving the cell super view. Doing it this way, you'd have three levels of views: one view to represent the display, 11 letter subviews, and as many subviews of each letter to represent the "on" pixels.

Comment: Pefect! The tip only to draw "on" digits reduzed the cpu usage significantly. Please find my updated code on github: https://github.com/drollig8/LEDBanner.git